# Traer registros diferencia de 2 minutos - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT t.Codigo, t.Cuenta, t.Nombre, t.NumeroRegistro, t.Fecha
FROM Tabla t
Where Codigo='10247'
```

El cual me genera este resultado

```
Codigo  Cuenta  Nombre      NumeroRegistro          Fecha
10247   150101  Pedro Pablo    7948362     2022-08-24 17:10:38.930
10247   150101  Pedro Pablo    7948367     2022-08-24 17:13:42.500
10247   150101  Pedro Pablo    7951185     2022-08-25 11:22:41.967
10247   150101  Pedro Pablo    7957117     2022-08-27 07:12:36.250
10247   150101  Pedro Pablo    7960040     2022-08-28 13:08:44.787
10247   150101  Pedro Pablo    7975963     2022-09-02 14:01:46.437
```

Lo que quiero es traer unicamente los registros que se realizaron en la misma fecha pero con
que este dentro de los 5 minutos

por ejemplo para ese resultado de arriba, las primeras 2 transacciones son las que quiero que me traiga
ya que la primera fue en fecha 2022-08-24 en el tiempo 17:10:38, y el segundo registro fue en la misma fecha
solo que 3 minutos despues

Como puedo realizar esto?

Comment: Quieres todos los registros agrupados cada 5 minutos?? o quieres que a partir de una fecha X traiga los registros que no sean mayores a x+5min ??

Comment: A partir de una fecha, todos los registros que hayan sido en la misma fecha pero con diferencia no menos de 5 minutos

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es usar LAG, para traer el registro anterior y luego calcular la diferencia entre las fechas.

Si la diferencia con el registro anterior es menor o igual al tiempo establecido, ponemos un flag.

```
Set dateformat ymd;
Declare @table table (
    Codigo varchar(10),
    Cuenta varchar(10),
    Nombre varchar(11),
    NumeroRegistro varchar(7),
    Fecha datetime);

Insert into @table (Codigo, Cuenta, Nombre, NumeroRegistro, Fecha)
values
('10247','150101','Pedro Pablo','7948362','2022-08-24 17:10:38.930'),
('10247','150101','Pedro Pablo','7948367','2022-08-24 17:13:42.500'),
('10247','150101','Pedro Pablo','7951185','2022-08-25 11:22:41.967'),
('10247','150101','Pedro Pablo','7957117','2022-08-27 07:12:36.250'),
('10247','150101','Pedro Pablo','7960040','2022-08-28 13:08:44.787'),
('10247','150101','Pedro Pablo','7975963','2022-09-02 14:01:46.437');

With source as
    (
   Select *,
    LAG(Fecha,1) over(PARTITION by Nombre order by Fecha) as anterior
        From @table t
), data as (
select t.*, case when DATEDIFF(minute,anterior,fecha) <=5 then 1 else 0 end as diferencia
    From source t
)
Select data.Codigo
    , data.Cuenta
    , data.Nombre
    , data.NumeroRegistro
    , data.Fecha
    from data 
where 
    (
     (diferencia=1) 
        or 
     (diferencia=0 and anterior is null)
    );
```

[image: Res1]

[Lag](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lag-y-lead-siguiente-y-anterior/)